# Could not start psc-ide-server process. Check the configured port number is valid. psc-ide-server error

Tags: node.js, atom-editor, purescript

My end goal is to use the Atom IDE plugin for [Purescript](https://github.com/nwolverson/atom-ide-purescript) which gives me the error:

> Could not start psc-ide-server process. Check the configured port
>   number is valid. psc-ide-server error

I just installed Purescript 0.8.2 using `npm`.

```
npm install -g purescript
...
purescript@0.8.2 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/purescript

  ✔ psc pre-build test passed successfully
  ✔ psc-bundle pre-build test passed successfully
  ✔ psc-docs pre-build test passed successfully
  ✔ psc-publish pre-build test passed successfully
  ✔ psci pre-build test passed successfully
```

Should it have the `psc-ide-server` and `psc-ide-client`? I see these folders in the purescript master branch and the [release doc](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases) mentions that it is now distributed with the compiler.
How do I access it?

In my `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/purescript/bin`, I see `psc-bundle,psc-docs,psc-publish,psc, psci` but no `psc-ide-server` and `psc-ide-client`

Comment: psc-ide is missing from the npm distribution right now. I think it should be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binaries are missing from the npm distribution for this release. You can get them with the release bundle from GitHub.

https://github.com/purescript/purescript/releases

If you put them in your path, `ide-purescript` should start working.